# How to format the twin logarithmic x axis tick labels to appear as powers of ten?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Both my x axis are in log scale. The upper x axis is a function of the the lower axis (squared, in this example).

While the lower axis tick labels are automatically formatted in powers of ten, the upper axis has different default formatting (scientific notation):

[image]

How do I fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

x = np.logspace(-9,0,10)
x2 = x**2
new_tick_locations = x[3:-3]
new_tick_labels = x2[3:-3]
y = np.ones(np.size(x))

ax1.semilogx(x,y)
plt.grid(True)
ax1.set_xlabel(r"Original x-axis: $X$")

ax2.set_xscale('log')
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax2.set_xticklabels(new_tick_labels)
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Modified x-axis: $X^2$")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are least two ways to fix this:

1. Format your `new_tick_labels` before assigning them in `ax2.set_xticklabels()`
2. Use `FuncFormater` to do both unit conversion and formating without the need to call `ax2.set_xticklabels()`

To go 1st way you would need to replace this line:

```
ax2.set_xticklabels(new_tick_labels)
```

with this block:

```
new_tick_labels = ['$\mathdefault{10^{%i}}$' % np.log10(l) 
                   for l in new_tick_labels]
ax2.set_xticklabels(new_tick_labels)
```

To benefit from `FuncFormater` replace the same line with:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: 
        '$\mathdefault{10^{%i}}$' % np.log10(x**2)))
```

You can also drop `new_tick_labels = x2[3:-3]` if you use `FuncFormater`.